# ‘Running Ragged’ hat not awarded

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2016

The description for the [‘Running Ragged’ hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/running-ragged) is

> earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack Overflow) within 15 days.

On December 19th (the first day of Winter Bash), I gained 150 or more reputation on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=reputation), [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11110/glorfindel?tab=reputation) and [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/18673/glorfindel?tab=reputation). Yet I’m still waiting for my hat.

[image]
[image]
[image]

<s>Does anybody know if there is any scheduled delay caused by the shipping company? Because I’d like to wear one of them on Christmas Eve.</s>

Did I miss some additional rule about this hat, or is this a bug? I joined these sites a while ago, so no association bonus was involved. I suppose Meta Stack Exchange *does* count for this hat, as it *does* for the similarly worded Polymath, and in any case, I now earned 150 reputation on Chess as well.

Comment: Maybe Meta.SE doesn't count? It's a meta, not a "real site".

Comment: Even then, I earned 150 reputation on Chess (on the 19th and the 20th combined).

Comment: Hmm. Worth mentioning that (and any other sites) in your Q. But I'm stumped. Also, I'm neutral on hats, so feel free to borrow any of the ones I accidentally earned....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep, there was a bug that prevented this hat from being awarded. Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Fix confirmed; I just got my Running Ragged hat.  Thanks.